# datatable not working when including a view inside another view

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatable, loadview

1) - The Controller Code

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {
        $dataView['content'] = $this->load->view('crud_view','', TRUE);
        //$dataView['content'] = 'crud_view';
        $this->load->view('masterpageTeste',$dataView);

    }
}
```

2) - The Section on MasterPage where I want to include the view's content

```
        <section class="content">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <?php
                    //$this->load->view($content);
                    echo $content;
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

The problem facing is that the view has datatable code

Comment: What about the javascript and the view containing the table?

Comment: Its nessesary to include nedest view ? Maybe load 2 separated view